# Not able to view Event emitted from Hyperledger composer in th UI

Tags: javascript, user-interface, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

How can I show Event notification in the UI ? 
I am able to subscribe to the event in my API, but I dont know how to display the same in the UI. The following code I used in my API to subscribe the event emitted from Hyperledger-composer

```
.then(function(){
    bizConn.on("event",evt =>{
    console.log('---Event Received---');
    temperature = evt.temperature;
    console.log('Temperature : ', temperature)  
})
```

This event is emitted when a particular transaction associated with this event is triggered. How can I distinguish between the normal transaction output and the event?

Let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: hi, see an example of consuming events in this sample (code: https://github.com/IBM/BlockchainEvents-CompositeJourney/blob/master/Web/public/scripts/events.js video: https://developer.ibm.com/patterns/automate-business-processes-via-blockchain-events/ - its using websockets / Composer REST server to consume events in the node based web UI app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get notifications in user applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987236/how-to-get-notifications-in-user-applications)

Comment: Already answered here, check out the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52987696/10529091